# How to calculate the non-intersecting area of two polygons?

Tags: geometry, polygon, computational-geometry

Is there an algorithm that can give me the area of the non-overlapping parts of two arbitrary polygons? I wasn't able to find anything that generalizes for two arbitrary polygons.

Comment: What do you know about these polygons? Perimeter? Are they cyclic? Regular? The question is too vague at the moment.

Comment: We know nothing about the polygons. They can be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Vatti's clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm) that works with arbitrary polygons and allows to find "xor" clipping polygon(s). Then you can calculate area of result.

[image]

This algorithm is used in [Clipper library](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper/documentation/Docs/Overview/_Body.htm) (opensource, has bindings to some programming languages)

Answer (score 0):

The area of a polygon is straightforward by the shoelace formula, and the non-overlapping area is the sum of the individual areas minus the area of the intersection.

The intersection polygon must be computed explicitly, for example using the Weiler & Atherton clipping algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton_clipping_algorithm.

Beware that the implementation is not trivial.